# Does Mapbox has a get user pan/swipe event? Can't find anything in Docs

Tags: react-native, mapbox, mapbox-android, mapbox-ios

**What I'm looking for?**

I want to get notified when the user swipes/pans the pan to check other locations.
The only only event I could find is [onPress](https://github.com/react-native-mapbox-gl/maps/blob/master/docs/MapView.md) but it is only fired when the user actually presses on the map, but if the user swipes the map to change view it doesn't get fired.

**What I need it for**

I want to know if the user swiped the map and the user's location is not the center of the map anymore. If yes, then show a button to center map around the user's location. Like I said, how do I know if the user swiped.

**What am I using**
Mapbox SDK for react-native (currently only testing on ios but I need it to work on ios and android in the future).

**What I have tried so far**

```
onRegionWillChange = { ( ) => this.myfunction() }
```

myfunction here only gets notified when the region loaded changes, not when the user is not centered anymore.

```
this._map.getCenter()
```

I user this to know if thee center of the map is the user's location. But I am looking again for the event that gets fired when the user swipes & then I would call this function to verify the swipe.

Any Help is very much apprechiated

Answer (score 1):

I've no experience using the SDK for react-native, but using the JS version you can use on `drag` events. It might lead you to a way to do it using the react-native SDK.

There are three types.

- `drag`
- `dragend`
- `dragstart`

This shows an example that listen for the `drag` event and writes out the current center of the map to console.

```
this._map.on("drag", (x) => {
  console.log(this._map.getCenter());
});
```